# Converting a Wordpress website into an offline Android application

Tags: android, html, wordpress, web-crawler

Recently I started my project to convert an online education resource to a mobile compatible wordpress site. I completed it and have no problems with it, however now I need to make this entire wordpress site converted into an Android application.

I have already looked into HTTrack and WP Cache plugins, however they do not seem to capture the menu's and I think this is because of the HTML5 inside the theme that I am using.

So basically, I have been able to capture most of the website and convert it into HTML, however pages such as /#&ui-page=0-55 in wordpress are not crawled nor grabbed.

The menus are very extensive and saving them one by one would take far too long.

After the entire process I plan on using PhoneGap to convert the application into an APK.

Thank you so much for the help, and I am so sorry if I am not clear, please let me recall what I mean if you have trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at wget to mirror the website? With the right paramter you can mirror a site and convert all of the dependencies.

```
wget -mk http://www.example.com/
```